# How upload buffer files in array to express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, multer

I have array with buffer files. I have been trying upload buffers to express server using multer for whole day.
Problem is my files pass by req.body.image. But multer finds files from req.files. Multer can't found files and alerted error. How fix this problem?

Front End code:

```
let UserPhoto = ["data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAQwAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABhY3NwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA9tYAAQAAAADTLQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"];
let formData = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < userPhoto.length; i++) {
      formData.append("files", userPhoto[i]);
    }

    axios
      .post(`v0/photo/${id}/User`, formData, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
}
```

Back End code:

```
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype.substr(0, 6) === "image/") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else cb(new ErrorCatcher("Зөвхөн зураг upload хийнэ үү.", 400), false);
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, director);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + "." + file.mimetype.split("/")[1]);
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: process.env.IMAGE_MAX_SIZE },
  fileFilter: fileFilter,
});
//authorize,
// permission("user", "operator", "manager", "admin"),
router
  .route("/:objectId/:objectType")
  .post(upload.array("files", 8), createImageConnect);
```

I was using formData. Result was same.

Comment: `userPhoto[i]` is a string, not a buffer. It's going to be treated as a string.

Comment: Thank you Quentin. How convert string to Buffer in FrontEnd? Do you have any idea?